# Rails 3.2.1: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. - c:/RailsInstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dll

I was working on a Rails 3.2.1 app last night and everything worked fine. However, this morning when I ran `rails server`, I got this weird problem:

```
> c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
> 36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   -
> c:/RailsInstaller
> /Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/digest/sha1.so (LoadError)
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
> m_require.rb:36:in `require'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
> lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
> lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
> lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
> lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
> m_require.rb:59:in `require'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
> m_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
> m_require.rb:35:in `require'
>         from c:/Users/user/rails_projects/fyff/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (requir ed)>'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
> m_require.rb:36:in `require'
>         from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
> m_require.rb:36:in `require'
>         from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I just spent quite some time looking for solutions, some of my findings are issues with the Rails installer:

```
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/102
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-dep_segfault
```

But the troubleshooting/fix doens't seem to apply to me, as I don't recall ever seeing 'FRAPS' or 'detours'.

Can anyone explain why this is happening all of a sudden? Any solution/attempt would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You say you were working on it the night before. You mean, specifically, that you ran `rails server` the night before and it worked? Can you retrace your steps regarding what changes you made between the last successful run of `rails server` and the subsequent error?

Comment: nothing,really. I shut down after working on view pages and the server was still working then, but this morning when I tried it, it gives the above error

Comment: So between the last time you ran `rails server` without getting an error, and the next time which produced an error, at the very least, you were "working on view pages". You're sure you didn't change (in any way) anything else at all between those two events? Install any Windows updates? Etc?

Comment: nothing I did manually, is there a way to trace changes on my system?

Comment: You can look at the Windows system log to determine if any updates were done. I think that's reaching a bit (unless a Windows update specifically changed your Rails install for some odd reason) but worth a check in the spirit of "examine anything that may have changed since it worked". Note that "since it worked" I mean from the last time you literally typed in the `rails server` command that did not give an error, not a point later than that.

Comment: fixed it...by restarting the system. Don't really know why but it worked, thanks for all your help @mbratch!

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for posting the resolution. Problems like that do leave one wondering... Somehow something got into a temporary state that the restart reset. Something to keep an eye on.

Comment: Glad you could fix your problem. Might I also suggest you use a Linux distro even through Virtual Box. It will really ease some of the development mains you may encounter just due to the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting seems to be the only fix for this issue. I've had it a couple of times for no apparent reason. But after reboot everything seems fine.